# Need help with dance studio

Tags: speakers

I am doing AV for a new dance studio thats being built. They do all types of dance in there. There are three studios, two are about 1300sqft and one is 2200sqft. I believe i am going to need some form of sub so the dancers can feel the music. The ceilings are open and are about 12-13 feet high. I cant figure out how much wattage or what speakers are going to be right for the space. Any help would be more then awesome! Thanks
Edit: needs to be in the air(other then an sub)

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the space, we can only guess.

my guess would be 2 pairs of 2way speakers with a 15" woofer. Targeit dance floor SPL should be no more than 110dba/115dbc. You can figure this out by taking into account the speakers sensitivity and max spl. If a speaker is rated at 90 dbspl @1w/1m 110db at 5m would be about 200w. As a rule always spec amps at 2.5x the power you need to account for headroom, 450w. Remember this is for a 90dbspl speaker and everything changes with your speaker choice. +3db for every doubling of power and -3db for every doubling of distance. The reference is usually 1w/1m.

This is per speaker depending on impedance of the speaker and how the amp behaves with different impedances. If you have two 8 ohm speakers linked to create 1 4ohm speaker you gain some efficiency, provided your amp can handle it.

It is also necessary to provide an interface and wasy to use volume control for the operator of the system, most likely a choreographer, so make sure you take that into account. Amps and graphic eqs and anything else in the system should be behind tamper proof plates.

Comment: defiantly keep the amps and controls away from users, a nice way to do it is a "zoner" such as made by Cloud, this allows you to give the instructor a nice easy interface, for you to keep the amps locked away remotely and also to provide an emergency muting interface for the fire-alarm.